# Safely remove stale files with msbuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a target that copies source files to a staging directory, this happens for multiple projects. In a later project, those files are passed into a type of compiler.

Currently that staging directory is not cleaned, so when a source file is deleted, a stale copy lives on in the staging directory.

What's the best way to clean that staging directory of stale files without negatively impacting my incremental build times? (ie. without fully deleting the staging directory each time)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achiev, possibly because you're using strange terminology. Normally when one talks about 'cleaning' in the context of build systems, it's a step where you run the opposite of a 'build' which deletes all artefacts created by the build. So there is no realy difference is between 'cleaning' a directory and deleting it? I think you mean something else though, what exactly? Provide a concrete example of what you want to happen or so.

Comment: @stijn Sure. During the build, files from Directory A are copied to Directory B for a set of projects. In a later project (same solution), all the files in Directory B are compiled. At no point in the build (or a Clean build) are the files in Directory B removed. So if you remove a file from Directory A (from source control), it will live on in Directory B unless manually removed. I would like a way to delete these 'stale' files in Directory B at the start of a build without simply deleting the entire Directory B (which would impact the incremental build). Does that make sense?

Comment: Sort of. So basically you want an extra build step which runs before the actual build and which lists all files in dir B, and then just deletes those which are not in dir A? Or whatever you have as master list for A; you do need a list somewhere, else it's guesswork. You should post code showing how the copying is donde, where you get the input files from etc. And add that information to your question (just like the info in your comment above actually belongs in your question as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this bit of script to clean up files which had been removed from the source, but still exist in the destination:

```
 <Target Name="DeleteStaleFiles">
   <!-- Remove stale files (files which have been deleted at the source but still exist in the destination).  -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <SourceFiles Include="@(SourceFiles->'$(Destination)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
        <DestinationFiles Include="$(Destination)**\*.*" />
        <StaleFiles Include="@(DestinationFiles)" Exclude="@(SourceFiles)" />
    </ItemGroup>    
    <Message Text="Deleting Stale Files: @(StaleFiles, '%0A')" Condition="'@(StaleFiles->Count())' &gt; 0"/>
    <Delete Files="@(StaleFiles)"/>     
  </Target>
```